# Identify a story about a detective with a psychic hand

Tags: story-identification, psychic

I read this story back in the 1980s.  It was from an anthology on fantasy from a used book store so it was likely written the 1960s.  The main character had a psychic ability, basically an invisible hand and he could manipulate things about an arms length away.  In the end, he kills his enemy by squeezing his heart with his psychic hand.  I recall the detective lost his hand hunting asteroids and had to change his career.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26778/is-there-a-known-space-story-about-a-field-that-catalyzes-combustion?s=3|0.1517

Answer (score 22):

The ["Gil the ARM"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gil_Hamilton) stories by [Larry Niven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Niven). Mostly short, noir mysteries. but they've been anthologized in a paperback several times. The 1995 *[Flatlander](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?280009)* seems to be the latest publication, and is [available as an e-book for kindle](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/flatlander-larry-niven/1021992317?ean=9780307556196) and [nook](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/flatlander-larry-niven/1021992317?ean=9780307556196) or through [audible.com](http://www.audible.com/pd/Sci-Fi-Fantasy/Flatlander-Audiobook/B00A6N7NLU) at least.

If I recall correctly the particular story you are interested in was "The Defenseless Dead".

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like the story I want is Death by Ecstasy which is in Worlds Best SF 1970.